Java Generics capture in Stream.toList()
I still have a point that I do not understand when working with Java generics and Lists. I will use here a Class<?> example to keep it simple, but it applies to any generic<?> type.
Here is the referenced java class:
(Note the comments in the below code.)
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.Temporal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyClass {

    private static Class<? extends Temporal> w(Class<? extends Temporal> a) {
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Class<? extends Temporal>> x = new ArrayList<>();
        x.add(Instant.class);

        // Compiles and runs without error.
        List<Class<? extends Temporal>> y = x.stream()
                                             .map(MyClass::w)
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Compiles and runs without error.
        y = x.stream()
             .toList();

        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Class<capture#7-of ? extends Temporal>> to
        // List<Class<? extends Temporal>>
        y = x.stream()
             .map(MyClass::w)
             .toList();
    }
}

The compile error is due to the call to method map, i.e.
.map(MyClass::w)

I don't understand why I get the compile error since method w() has the same return type as its parameter type.
Thanks for help.

The compile error is because you have a semi-colon after the call to map(), so it’s trying to assign the resulting stream to y, which is of type List.

@rimesc That is clearly one syntax error.  But fix that and the OP's problem still exists.

since method w() has the same return type as its parameter type -- no, it has not. It is an unfortunate quirk of the Java syntax, that it looks that way. But the types represented by the ? in the return value and the one in the parameter declaration are different. Hence, even though their bounds are the same, the generic parameter types are not.

@dirk Thanks for the answer. It seems there are subtilities in the use of the '<?>' type that I still don't understand. Is there a place where the difference you are talking about is explained?

The signature of your w method looks off. Shouldn't that be <T> Class<T> w(Class<T> a) instead? Not that it fixes your immediate problem, but ? extends Temporal and ? extends Temporal are two independently captured types, they are not the same type. The final return type is List<? extends Class<? extends Temporal>>.

I've tested your reproducible code example.
In my understanding the issue you have is coming from the .toList(); method being used on the return of the .map(); method.
The .map(); method returns a <R> Stream<R> object, so in your case basically <? of <? extend Temporal> if i'm correct.
Due to your declaration of the y variable as a List<Class<? extends Temporal>> the .map(); method could return an object that can be set to the y variable after being converted to a List<? of <? extends Temporal>> by the .toList(); method. But it doesn't return such an object in all possible cases thus your compiler throws you an error.
Now you may ask why the .collect(Collectors.toList()); call over the Collectors class works and a simple .toList(); call doesn't. In the first case the collect method of the map interface in connection with the .toList(); call onto the Collectors class groups the elements of the <R> Stream<R> return of the called .map(); method into a finite and clearly defined group of elements before converting it into a list. That leaves no room for interpretation from the side of the compiler thus you get no error.
Generics fulfill their purpose here. They stop you from saving objects with mismatching properties into a list of objects with properties you defined.
Your code works if you define the y variable as List<?>, but im pretty sure that's not what you are getting at.
Im happy for anyone to correct or improve my answer, because i am for sure not the most knowledgeable person regarding this topic.

I see what you mean. But I don't find natural that the 'toList()' method should return something like 'List<? extends Class<? extends Temporal>>' and not List<Class<? extends Temporal>> as all the elements from stream are of type Class<? extends Temporal>. Anyway, thanks for help
